# How to use/wrap Serpent/blowfish/whirlpool Encryption Engine Code?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have search through Google for serpent and blowfish encryption wrapper.
I have found the engine of serpent/blowfish/whirlpool here:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptodotnet/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/classlesshasher/
- http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

I have browse through the code. however I have no idea how to wrap the serpent and blowfish encryption engine. Could anyone gave me some clue? thanks.